# UITextViewにて選択範囲だけ動的にカラーを変更したい

Tags: objective-c

このコードにて文字の選択範囲の取得まではできているのですが、
selectedTextに入ってる文字のカラーを赤に変更し、
そのままUItextviewに適応させるやり方で苦戦しております。
ご教授のほどお願いします！

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
NSLog(@"called!:textViewDidChangeSelection");
selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:textView.selectedRange];
```

}

Comment: UItextviewのタイプミスです！
NSAttributedStringについてもう少し深く調べたいと思います

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テキストの属性、例えばフォント、フォントの大きさ、文字の色、文字の背景色、行の中央揃え、右寄せ、このような属性を操作するには、`NSAttributedString`クラスを使います。`UITextView`のプロパティ`attributedText`で、`NSAttributedString`型のテキストを取得できます。
テキストの属性をあとから変更するには、`NSMutableAttributedString`クラスである必要があります。
テキストビューをStoryboardで設置している場合、テキストの属性を`Attributed`にしておきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下、ボタンを押したら、テキストビュー`textView`の選択部分を赤色に変更するプログラムです。

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
    // テキストの選択範囲を取得。
    NSRange selectedRange = self.textView.selectedRange;
    // 1文字以上を選択していたら
    if (selectedRange.length > 0) {
        // attributedStringを取得して、Mutableにコピー。
        NSMutableAttributedString *theText = [self.textView.attributedText mutableCopy];
        // 選択部分だけ文字色を赤に変える。
        [theText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: UIColor.redColor range: selectedRange];
        // 変更を加えたattributedStringを戻す。
        self.textView.attributedText = theText;
    }
}
```

`NSAttributedString`について、把握する項目がちょっとしたボリュームになります。じっくり勉強してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
早速試しつつ、検証したいとおもいます。

Comment: 私が考えていた機能が上記コードで実装できました！
ご教授ありがとうございます。　助かりました！